# File is referenced externally but added in package.config in asp projects

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, package, libraries

I am currently working on jQuery upgrade in my project.

This is my `packages.config` file of my ASP.NET MVC project:

```
<packages>   
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />   
    <package id="jquery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net48" /> 
</packages>
```

The jquery in our ASP.NET MVC project is referenced externally from the `Scripts` folder, but I could see its mentioned with different version in `packages.config`.

Can I proceed with deleting below line from `packages.config` in my ASP.NET MVC project ?

```
<package id="jquery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Would it have any impact? Do I need to change it some other places in my ASP.NET MVC project?